# "Address already in use": I'm misunderstanding UDP

Tags: udp

Is it possible for two or more programs to monitor UDP packages on a single port?  We have a device that converts RS-232 data to UDP on port 55110, but it appears I can only have one listener running on a given computer. Attempts at a second cause "Address already in use". Apparently there is some other program on the computer listening, because REUSE => 1 doesn't help. Multiple users would like to sample the data. I apologize for so basic a question.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for two programs to listen on the same UDP port, but both programs have to specify that they want to allow the port to be shared.  Here is an excerpt from my code that tells the OS to do this (called just before calling bind() on the UDP socket):

```
if (allowShared)
{
   const int trueValue = 1;
   setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &trueValue, sizeof(trueValue));
#ifdef __APPLE__   // MacOS/X requires an additional call also
   setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &trueValue, sizeof(trueValue));
#endif
}
```

Comment: Only broadcast & multicast packets will be multiplexed, unicast packets will only get sent to the first socket.

Answer (score 2):

udp_reflector is a simple opensource tool to get around the "Address already in use" issue when working with udp data.

http://code.google.com/p/udp-reflector/

Answer (score 0):

Even after you get two applications listening on the same UDP port, as Steve-o's comment says, unicast packets don't get multiplexed anyway.  This means that each packet will get sent to *one* of the listening applications.

The best way to do this is to set up a listener on port 55110 that will just re-send every incoming packet to a list of other ports on localhost, where your multiple client applications are listening.

Comment: The idea of using UDP was to have a simple way of sending data from instruments to all the computers in the system so that a user could write simple code to "tap into" the data stream, knowing only the port number.  Is this a misuse of UDP?

Comment: @javery: No, that's fine - but you need to use UDP broadcast (or multicast, but broadcast is simpler) to achieve that.